# Normalize a row of data in a query - Turn one row into many

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a better way of doing this , I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have a table built by as vendor that looks like the below:

```
Customer, Date, Desc1, Qty1, Price1, Desc2, Qty2, Price2, Desc3, Qty3, Price3
```

I want a result set that returns this;

```
Customer, Date, Desc, Qty, Price
```

I am doing it today by the following solution , anyone have something better or more efficient?

```
Select Customer, Date, Desc1, Qty1, Price1
UNION ALL
Select Customer, Date, Desc2, Qty2, Price2
UNION ALL
Select Customer, Date, Desc3, Qty3, Price3
```

Comment: what you have is fine, if you have a common where clause though, you could put this in a with statement

Comment: The *best* solution is to fix your bad table schema. This is not even 1NF: you have repeating groups. Your table should look like the output of your query, perhaps with the inclusion of a `line_number` column.

Comment: Alternatives do exist, but it depends on the type of database you are using. Please **always** tag your questions with the database (e.g. Sybase?
 MySQL? SQlL Serer? Oracle? ...... more)

Comment: The OP does mention a vendor, and so may not have control over the table's structure (awful as it is).

Comment: Correct...it is a vendor table so I am unable to modify it.  As it relates to the solution provided...my data actually has 5 columns duplicated over 11 instances....so the Cross Apply in performance cut my query time in half.  Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative for SQL Server; it uses `cross apply` and `values` and it is an efficient and very flexible substitute for the `unpivot` command and is really useful for "normalizing" data.

```
select Customer, Date, ca.description, ca.qty, ca.price
from YourTable
cross apply (
   values
      (Desc1, Qty1, Price1)
    , (Desc2, Qty2, Price2)
    , (Desc3, Qty3, Price3)
    , (Desc4, Qty4, Price4)
    ) ca (description, qty, price)
```

**NB**: Each row within the `values` area forms a new row of output, so when laid out as you see above it is visually similar to the final layout.

For more details on this see: [Spotlight on UNPIVOT, Part 1](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/spotlight-on-unpivot-part-1.html) (Brad Schultz)

Answer (score 1):

The `UNION ALL` method works just fine.  However, you may have different performance or readability with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT t1.Customer,
    t1.[Date],
    x.[Desc],
    x.Qty,
    x.Price
FROM UnnamedTable t1
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (Desc1, Qty1, Price1),
        (Desc2, Qty2, Price2),
        (Desc3, Qty3, Price3)
    ) x ([Desc], Qty, Price);
```

That's assuming that each repeating group is really the same data type.  That is, `Qty1`, `Qty2`, and `Qty3` are all `int` (or similar), and so on.

Alternately, you could use an UNPIVOT expression, but, honestly, I find UNPIVOT's syntax to be extremely arcane.

Comment: ditto the unpivot = arcane comment :)